# How to made command work with capitalize and non capitalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hey So Im making an discord js Bot and im trying to make an help command

My Curret Command

```
 if (!args[0]) return msg.channel.send(normal);
    else if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "Everyone") return msg.channel.send(everyone);
    else if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "ChannelMaker") return msg.channel.send(channelmaker);
    else if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "Admin") return msg.channel.send(admin);
    else return msg.channel.send(normal);
```

The thing is it do work but however if i type '-help everyone' it still says the normal not the everyone

Do Anyone Know What happend and why i cant do that ?

Comment: Fixed Im too stupid i forget to turn 'E,C,M,A' to non capitalize

Answer (score 0):

I see that you fixed it. Please close this subject then ^^'

Also

> else if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "Everyone") return msg.channel.send(everyone);

you useed `toLowerCase()` so it's impossible that is get equal to `Everyone` since the first letter is uppercase